# Retrieve Images Not Working Via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, image

I am trying to retrieve Images using the REST API from iOS/Android.

The issue I’m running into is when the images are stored in the **/sites/siteName**  directory, the REST call does not work. Let me explain further:

My REST call:  `//tenant/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/siteName/PublishingImages/image.jpg')/$value`

- That call does not work. I get a `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException` - The file `/sites/siteName/PublishingImages/image.jpg` does not exist.
- The file does indeed exist because inside the web browser I can view the image using: `//tenant.com/sites/siteName/PublishingImages/image.jpg`

The REST call that does work is:

- `//tenant.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`

  `('/News/PublishingImages/image.jpg')/$value`

  - That returns the image as expected.

I’m not a SharePoint developer so my knowledge is very light. But, I’m confused to as why those calls do not work.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned code to get file using REST API call.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)/File/$value
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
```

**Example**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

var response = client.GetAsync("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)/File/$value", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
var fileContent = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

**`GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` Examples**

//The root folder of the Shared Documents library
`_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')`

//The file a.txt from the Plans library
`_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Plans')/Files('a.txt')/$value`

Please [check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx) for more information

Comment: Have you got it working?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The first bit of code unless I'm missing something requires javascript to get the SP.AppContext working. I'm doing this in native iOS and Android. When I use PostMan to test the call as you suggest it states there's no appContext.   The other examples do not work as well, still says the files do not exist.

Comment: Check my updated answer... If it will help you

Comment: If I only know the file name and path, how do I get the item Id of the file?

Comment: Use this **_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Plans')/Files('a.txt')/$value**

Comment: To verify my call is correct. If my image is located:  **//tenant.com/sites/NA/PublishingImages/Pages/pics/image.png**


The api call will look like: **//tenant.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/NA/PublishingImages/Pages/pics')/Files(‘image.png')/$value**

If that is correct, I still get file not found.

Comment: Try this.... //tenant.com//sites/NA/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/PublishingImages/P‌​ages/pics')/Files(‘image.png')/$value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40701/discussion-between-karl-barek-and-hardik).